# Model.generate stop code execution without any error

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am pretty new to HF, this is my first attempt to use a model. The problem is `model.generate` kinda abrupt the script execution without any error. Here’s my code:

```py
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('Salesforce/codet5-base')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('Salesforce/codet5-base')

text = "write for cycle"
input_ids = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

print("before")
generated_ids = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=8)
print("after")

print(tokenizer.decode(generated_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

This code gives me no output except “before”. Also, I’ve tried other models with the same result. It looks the issue on my side… I’ll be very grateful for your help. Thanks!

Env:

```
- `transformers` version: 4.30.0.dev0
- Platform: macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
- Python version: 3.9.16
- Huggingface_hub version: 0.14.1
- Safetensors version: 0.3.1
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 2.0.1 (False)
- Tensorflow version (GPU?): not installed (NA)
- Flax version (CPU?/GPU?/TPU?): not installed (NA)
- Jax version: not installed
- JaxLib version: not installed
- Using GPU in script?: <fill in>
- Using distributed or parallel set-up in script?: <fill in>
```

Logs:

```
loading file vocab.json from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/vocab.json
loading file merges.txt from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/merges.txt
loading file added_tokens.json from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/added_tokens.json
loading file special_tokens_map.json from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/special_tokens_map.json
loading file tokenizer_config.json from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/tokenizer_config.json
loading configuration file config.json from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/config.json
Model config T5Config {
  "_name_or_path": "/content/drive/MyDrive/CodeT5/pretrained_models/codet5_base",
  "architectures": [
    "T5ForConditionalGeneration"
  ],
  "bos_token_id": 1,
  "d_ff": 3072,
  "d_kv": 64,
  "d_model": 768,
  "decoder_start_token_id": 0,
  "dense_act_fn": "relu",
  "dropout_rate": 0.1,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "feed_forward_proj": "relu",
  "gradient_checkpointing": false,
  "id2label": {
    "0": "LABEL_0"
  },
  "initializer_factor": 1.0,
  "is_encoder_decoder": true,
  "is_gated_act": false,
  "label2id": {
    "LABEL_0": 0
  },
  "layer_norm_epsilon": 1e-06,
  "model_type": "t5",
  "n_positions": 512,
  "num_decoder_layers": 12,
  "num_heads": 12,
  "num_layers": 12,
  "output_past": true,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "relative_attention_max_distance": 128,
  "relative_attention_num_buckets": 32,
  "task_specific_params": {
    "summarization": {
      "early_stopping": true,
      "length_penalty": 2.0,
      "max_length": 200,
      "min_length": 30,
      "no_repeat_ngram_size": 3,
      "num_beams": 4,
      "prefix": "summarize: "
    },
    "translation_en_to_de": {
      "early_stopping": true,
      "max_length": 300,
      "num_beams": 4,
      "prefix": "translate English to German: "
    },
    "translation_en_to_fr": {
      "early_stopping": true,
      "max_length": 300,
      "num_beams": 4,
      "prefix": "translate English to French: "
    },
    "translation_en_to_ro": {
      "early_stopping": true,
      "max_length": 300,
      "num_beams": 4,
      "prefix": "translate English to Romanian: "
    }
  },
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.30.0.dev0",
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 32100
}

loading weights file pytorch_model.bin from cache at /Users/zonder/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--Salesforce--codet5-base/snapshots/4078456db09ba972a3532827a0b5df4da172323c/pytorch_model.bin
Generate config GenerationConfig {
  "_from_model_config": true,
  "bos_token_id": 1,
  "decoder_start_token_id": 0,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "transformers_version": "4.30.0.dev0"
}

All model checkpoint weights were used when initializing T5ForConditionalGeneration.

All the weights of T5ForConditionalGeneration were initialized from the model checkpoint at Salesforce/codet5-base.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use T5ForConditionalGeneration for predictions without further training.
Generation config file not found, using a generation config created from the model config.
before
Generate config GenerationConfig {
  "_from_model_config": true,
  "bos_token_id": 1,
  "decoder_start_token_id": 0,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "transformers_version": "4.30.0.dev0"
}
```

Comment: Could you run `transformers-cli env` in a terminal and parse its output?

Comment: Sure. Updated the main post

Comment: Does downgrading transformers to the latest stable version (4.29.2) solves the issue?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see I'm using dev branch. I gonna try it right now, thank you!

Comment: Could you also tell me how I should manage the transformers library? Now I'm just cloning the repo. But I guess there must be other way like composer in PHP or npm in NodeJs...

Comment: There are multiple options, I like to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) (install it with `pip install virtualenv` if it's not on your machine), then cd in your working directory, create a virtualenv `virtualenv venv`, activate it `source venv/bin/activate`, and install your dependencies `pip install transformers`.

Comment: Thanks! Did this. Now I have 4.29.2. But it changed nothing... :(

Comment: If you're sure your script runs in your virtualenv, this could be an issue with macos, you should probably open an issue on github